# What is equivalent of Esri Shapefile metadata in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis, metadata

It is possible to enter a lot of information in an ESRI Shapefile metadata in ArcCatalog.

Is there something similar with a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database?

Is there a non-ESRI tool out there that makes it as easy as ArcCatalog to edit and view metadata of PostGIS tables?

What about ArcMap, QGIS, etc integration? It is very nice and convenient to search for a layer in ArcMap. Just search, drag and drop.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify whether the PG database is enterprise geodatabase-enabled (in which case metadata is trivial, but not portable) or whether it is a standalone PostgreSQL instance (in which case metadata is non-standardized). Please also include the versions of ArcGIS and PostgreSQL involved. It is GIS SE policy to have one question per Question,  so please clarify that as well.

Comment: I think the question clearly states a non-geodatabase/ non-ESRI enabled PostGIS/ PostgreSQL database.